# How to configure Firebase relatime database rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

We receive Firebase warning emails about our realtime database having insecure rules. Which is true, but I am struggling with how to change them. Our application is about 2 apps with a Chat functionality between a passenger and a driver.

This is what we store in the database:
[image]

Currently we have:

```
  {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Access should be granted if driverId / passengerId are supplied in the database read or write request.
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess there is no solution to this problem? Any Firebase expert at all on SO??

Comment: I think You should use authentication part for that. Is it possible to redesign workflow of project?

Answer (score 1):

I have only basic info about Firebase rules. I hope my below rules can help or atleast give you some idea about how to approach your situation.
So basically for read and write requests, we'll check if your data has the field `driverId` of `passengerId` or not:

```
{
  "rules": {
   "chats": {
      ".read": data.hasChildren([‘driverId’, ‘passengerId’]) === "true"
      ".write": newData.hasChildren([‘driverId’, ‘passengerId’]) === "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Here, `newData` corresponds to the incoming data and `data` corresponds to the data already and curently residing in the database.

More help can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/get-started) in Firebase's official documentation for security rules.

Comment: Actually, this didnt work. I tried below rules, but they give permission error:
{
  "rules": {
       "$chat": {
            "$trip": {
                "$text": {
            ".read": "data.hasChildren(['driverId', 'passengerId']) === true",
            ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['driverId', 'passengerId']) === true"
                }
        }
    }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

Your rules allow anyone to read & write anything anywhere. You should use authentication (to be able to identify users by their UID in the rules), structure you db so that information with different access logic is stored in different paths, then write rules to enforce your access logic.